# Jinja2 templates for latex - tutorials

Tags: latex, jinja2, jupyter

I was wondering if someone can point me to the tutorials on how to create custom Jinja2 templates for LaTeX, so that I can use it in with nbconvert to convert Jupyter notebook into LaTeX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that is highly undocumented. I would suggest asking on the mailing list or directly open an issue on GitHub (`jupyter/nbconvert` repo)

The normal template informations you find will work with one difference that you need to replace the template extension from `.tpl` to `.tplx`and replace the jinja delimiters: `{%` to `((*` for blocks , `{{` to `(((` for variable interpolations and `{#` to `((=` for comments + all the symetric closing markers. The reasoning is that latex uses `{` heavily and you want to avoid conflict.

Otherwise there is close to no difference between latex and non-latex templates.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [tutorial](https://github.com/jupyter/ngcm-tutorial/blob/master/Part-2/nbconvert_templates/Nbconvert%20templates.ipynb) from the IPython/Jupyter Workshop at the NGCM Summer Academy (official `jupyter` github).